# Implement custom function on Django search_fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a model with an ISBN field.
ISBN (International Standard Book Number) may be ISBN10 (10 digits) or ISBN13 (13 digits). I can convert 10 to 13 and 13 to 10 with a custom function.
The point is I want Django to search in ISBN field, no matter if it is ISBN10 or ISBN13 (the field accepts both). To do that, it is necessary to include the convert function somewhere. For example: if the value of my search is 8489691207 I want Django to search that value and the converted value to ISBN13 (9788489691209).

I'm using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Alasdair's answer (thank you):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from isbnlib import get_isbnlike, is_isbn10, is_isbn13, to_isbn10, to_isbn13

class Question_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        queryset, use_distinct = super(Question_Admin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        isbn = get_isbnlike(search_term, level='normal')
        if isbn:
            if is_isbn10(isbn[0]):
                converted = to_isbn13(isbn[0])
            else:
                converted = to_isbn10(isbn[0])
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(Q(isbn=isbn[0]) | Q(isbn=converted))
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the [`get_search_results`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) method for your model admin.

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        if is_isbn10(search_term):
            search_term = convert_to_isbn13(search_term)
        queryset, use_distinct = super(BookAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
```

self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
            return queryset, use_distinct

Comment: I think something is missing. Perhaps my question is not as clear as I thought, but what I need is to make a WHERE OR query, because I don't know what kind of isbn (10 or 13) is stored in the db. It is possible that the search_term is ok or maybe it is necesarry to convert it to 13 (or 10, depending on the original isbn search_term).

Comment: I answer my own question. Thanks for your help.